# How to get last inserted record in Meteor mongo?

Tags: mongodb, angular, angular-meteor

I want to get last inserted item in minimongo. currently i'm doing it in this way (code on client side):

```
addBook()
  {
    BookCollection.insert(
      this.book , ( err , insertedBook_id )=>
      {
        this.book_saved = true;
        console.group('Output:')
        console.log(err);
        console.log( insertedBook_id );
        console.log(
          BookCollection.find({_id: insertedBook_id})
            .fetch()
        );
        console.groupEnd();
        //this.router.navigate(['/book', insertedBook_id]);
      }
    );
  }
```

Output in console:

```
undefined
t6Lwrv4od854tE7st
[]
```

As you can see, when i redirect to newly created page, i cant find a book, but in mongo shell i clearly see that record was added. Should i wait for some event  like `BookCollection.insert(this.book).then( . . . )`? Please help me!)

When i go back to the 'all books page', i see new record and can click, all works normal, no errors.

In the /book controller:

```
 ngOnInit()
  {
    this.sub = this.curr_route.params.subscribe(
      params=>
      {
        this.book = BookCollection.findOne( params[ '_id' ] ); // .fetch() == []

        //if(!this.book)
        //    this.router.navigate(['/books']);

        Meteor.subscribe(
          'book' , params[ '_id' ] , ()=>
          {
            this.book = BookCollection.findOne( params[ '_id' ] );
          } , true
        )

        console.groupCollapsed( 'BookDetailsCardComponent log data:' )
        console.group( 'Book:' );
        console.log( this.book );
        console.groupEnd();
        console.groupEnd();

      } , true
    );

  }
```

Comment: How are you loading the document in your /book component? Is that where you are seeing the error?

Comment: I dont see ANY errors... The problem is that just after insert i can't find new record...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a timing issue. The `_id` is most likely created and returned immediately while the actual data is inserted into the database, which would explain why doing a `find()` on that `_id` right away comes back as an empty array.

Is there a reason you are doing your insert from the client rather than doing it on the server and using a Meteor method to initiate it? Changing to this approach might resolve your issue.